# Is it possible to edit a CSS style after bootstrap has done it's magic?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am totally new to bootstrap and not brill with jquery so apologies if this is a stupid question. Is it possible to hook a jquery event into my page that will be called after bootstrap has worked out where everything will go in its grid. I want to modify the background image in a CSS class depending on the layout bootstrap sets.

Comment: _"not brill with jquery"_ What's that mean?

Comment: It's a species of platfish. I'd go for a `$(window).on('load', function() { // do whatever })`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is check for the DOM to be ready so you know Bootstrap is done. I don't think you can edit CSS classes directly with jQuery, but what you could do is have 2 CSS classes that differ only by background image, then set the elements to use that other class with jQuery after checking whatever conditions you are looking for.